# How can I access to every fourth element in a multiple rows?

Tags: html, css

I have something like this

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content { width:100%;}
.item {width:20%, float: left}
```

- So they are 5 in a row, and im using nth-child(4n+4) to style every 4th element, but is not working!

Because at first row its the 4th element then 9th element 14th and so on! is there any thing I can solve this!

Comment: or `nth-of-type(4n)`

Comment: If this topic is a duplicate, that's not a duplicate of the subject that has been linked… The difference is that we have an offset, here.

Answer (score 2):

**New answer**

I see you updated your question.
"5 in a row" means we have to stylize each `5n` elements.
Then, you only have to add `+4` to start stylizing the 4th element, when n=0.

Here is my answer modified accordingly to your code:

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.item:nth-child(5n+4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
</div>
```

---

**Old answer**

No need for `+4` in that case.
Here is a working snippet:

```css
.item:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
  <div class="item">x</div>
</div>
```

Anyway, I don't know what you did wrong if you were using `4n+4`, that works too!

Answer (score 1):

You have **5 elements** per row and you need to access the **4th** within each row so you should do this:

```css
.item {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item:nth-child(5n + 4) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well exactly that right, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will style every 4th div.

```
div:nth-child(4n)
{
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.item:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here it is working on a JS Bin:
http://jsbin.com/xafubixoja/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

***.item:nth-child(4n)***

```css
.item:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned no need for the `+4`

*But since i finished the snippet anyway I'll post it.*

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');

var i = 0;

items.forEach((item) => {
  i++;
  item.innerHTML = i;
});
```

```css
div.item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1px 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.content div:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```